# Showing continuity of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, $M$ a closed subspace of $X$ such that $X/M$ is finite dimensional.  Let $x_1+M, \ldots, x_n+M\}$  be a basis of $X/M$ and let $Z$ be the linear span of $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$. We can show that for every $x\in X$ there exist unique $z(x)\in Z$ and $m(x)\in M$ such that $x=z(x)+m(x)$.  I want to show that the function $x\mapsto m(x)$ is a linear operator.

It can be shown that it is linear. But how to show it to be bounded? Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Corollary of Hahn Banach, let $V_i$ be the vector space spanned by $M$ and $x_i$, $M$ is closed in $V_i$, consider $a_i$ the linear function on $V_i$ defined by $a_i(x_i)=1$, $a_i(M)=0$, it is bounded since its kernel is $M$. Hahn Banach implies that you can extend it to $b_i$ on $X$. Write $b=\sum b_i$, show that $z(x)=b(x)$.

Comment: Actually this exercise is given in Magginson's book prior to the chapter containing Hahn Banach theorem.